# Changing Xib file presented based on Device rotation in iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uiview, autorotate

I'm trying to achieve the following:

I have two nib files, one in portrait view and one in landscape named WHMainViewController and WHMainLandscapeView, respectively.

I have one UIViewController named WHMainViewController.

I would like to present the WHMainViewController when in portrait view and WHMainLandscapeView when in landscape view.

I've looked into these functions:

```
-(void)orientationChanged:(NSNotification *)object{ UIDeviceOrientation deviceOrientation = [[object object] orientation];

if (deviceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait ) { 
}
else if (deviceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft || deviceOrientation ==    UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight) {
}
```

How should I implement them though?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This website provides an excellent tutorial on this issue:
http://www.theappcodeblog.com/2011/03/30/orientation-change-tutorial-change-the-view-when-the-orientation-changes/

By setting up two UIViews within the Xib of WHMainViewController.

Then connect two IBOutlets two the two views with one named portraitView and the other as landscapeView.

When the device rotates, update the view accordingly by setting

```
self.view = self.portraitView;
```

or

```
self.view = self.landscapeView;
```

Answer (score -1):

```
-(void)orientationChanged:(NSNotification *)object{ UIDeviceOrientation deviceOrientation = [[object object] orientation];

if (deviceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait ) { 
    WHMainViewController *VC = [[WHMainViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"WHMainViewController" bundle:nil];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:VC animated:YES];
}
else if (deviceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft || deviceOrientation ==    UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight) 
{
    WHMainViewController *VC = [[WHMainViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"WHMainLandscapeView" bundle:nil];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:VC animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: Hm.. This doesn't seem to work since I need to be able to load the landscape or portrait nib from a single view whenever the device is rotated. I want to switch views not push new views onto the initial view controller.